# How to prevent objects declared as local variables from being allocated in the stack?

Tags: c++, optimization, arm, embedded

I am struggling with following performance problem while compiling C++ for a small ARM processor using the ARM/Keil compiler.

Inside a function that does some processing I have code with following structure:

```
{
    MyClass temp = global_variable_input;

    Operation 1 on temp;
    Operation 2 on temp;
    ...
    Operation N on temp;

    global_variable_output = temp;
}
```

MyClass is used to model a mathematical object and the only member is a 32 bit integer (that is, the complete size of the object is 4 bytes).

All operations involve using either an overloaded operator or a method of MyClass and change the value of 'temp' as a result. Some operations are trivial and inlined (method declared inline in the class), and some are more complex and need to generate a call to the method.

Having a look at the assembler code generated by the compiler for my routine I noticed that the compiler allocates space for "temp" in the stack and every single operation (also the inlined ones!) store the result of the operation in that place in the stack, to then just continue using the value stored in the register from last operation. For the non-inline ones, the compiler pass a pointer to the object (this) in register r1 and a pointer to another object created in the stack to store the result in register r0.

The code implements a signal processing algorithm and you can imagine it as a sequence of arithmetic operations on temp, so having this additional "store" instruction with the corresponding memory access after every single operation (which might be just one single opcode) introduces a massive performance penalty in the implementation.

Ideally I would expect the compiler to complete the operation using only a register instead of keeping an stacked version of "temp" that needs to be updated after every operation.

Another wish would be for it to pass the current value of the object to the methods simply using a register (like the ARM C calling convention specifies for normal C functions) and getting the result in the same way, instead of using pointers to memory locations.

Am I asking for too much? How can I get my ARM/Keil compiler to work in that way?

PS: The function is simple enough so it's not like the compiler needs to allocate my variable in stack because it ran out of registers. I suspect the reason why it does it is that it feels a need to have a pointer to pass to the non-inlined methods, and then believes it is necessary to keep the value in stack always up to date.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `MyClass& temp = global_variable_input;`?
`

Comment: Have you tried with different optimization levels?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try the reference. But I can imagine then the compiler will find it even more justified to update the value after every operation? (As it is now a reference to a global variable and someone else might be using it )

Comment: Yeah I have tried different optimization levels but even with -O3 the compiler behaves this way. Only the combination of O3 + inlining ALL methods seemed to cause an improvement.

Comment: Did you try with `g++ -O3 -flto` both at compile and at link time? Did you try with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and/or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler?

Comment: No, I haven't. I use Keil ARM compiler v5 (previous to Clang). Porting the whole thing wouldn't be trivial as I believe inline assembler and pragmas, intrinsics, etc., wouldn't be compatible with Clang. However, I will try to find out if the update would fix the problem and if that were the case I will consider the port... Thanks!

Comment: per the rules of the language, to be re-entrant you need a new copy of those variables every time you enter the function, so by definition, whatever they cannot fit in registers, has to go on a stack.  if you dont want them on the stack then you cannot use local variables, make the function such that it doesnt need to use the stack or use static locals which are just context limited globals.  or use globals.  Or pass a structure in (essentially global with respect to this function is somewhere outside).

Comment: Or use another programming language that does not support re-entrant functions.

Comment: if all the operations are on the stack and all the intermediate variables, I would check your command line doesnt seem like you are optimizing.  Did -O2 or even -O1 greatly reduce the stack usage?  Did it change the code at all?  It should have made a dramatic effect.

Comment: Your other option if this is a performance issue is let the compiler make the first pass, then use the output assembly language and hand tune it, and/or write the function by hand in ASM from scratch.

Comment: Hi dwelch, thanks for your comment. The issue here is that the object fits perfectly in a register as it was made deliberately small (4 bytes) to achieve precisely that. If I make the function use a global variable instead of the stack I would still have the performance penalty associated with the memory accesses.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have this performance problem all over the signal processing code as this class is used very often, and the code is quite big. It wouldn't be realistic to re-write all that in ASM. I would rather port everything to C where I am confident it will generate the code I expect.

Comment: You may want to make sure that you can get the performance you need. Make sure that if you use `#pragma inline=forced` for all the functions called, that it meets your performance needs. It will give you the best possible performance. If that works, start backing out the `#pragma` from certain functions to see if you can determine where the bottleneck is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reference like

```
MyClass& temp = global_variable_input;
```

would avoid having a full copy of `MyClass` allocated on the stack (local storage)

Though any of

```
Operation 1 on temp;
Operation 2 on temp;
// ...
```

will affect the original `global_variable_input` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately my performance problem would then still remain.

Answer (score -3):

You may change your class into a struct.  It will store on the stack rather than the heap.